# How to setup shareable Java project?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Java-based automation framework project which I need to share with other test projects. In other words, I need to share the code as a library, so that other projects can just consume it. What do I need to do so that I can create a sharable code base, instead of manually copy pasting it?

Also, how can I implement versioning with this approach?

Comment: Do you use Gradle or Maven for dependency management ?

Comment: 1. You can compile code into jars for other code bases to use 2. Git 3. Maven 4. Gradle

Comment: Is there a way to not bundle in a jar and/or not share it on maven central publically but just pull down as a module, similar to what git submodule does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding sharing the code (Code reuse):
 You can package the project as jar and add that jar in other projects. The preferred way to do this would be to use either gradle/maven as they have well defined structure and in most cases plugin supports. See this : https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-libraries/. Please make sure there are adequate unit test for the library so that other projects can use your library with confidence.

For versioning the library:
Using gradle/maven with a VCS (git/ hg) can make your life easier. As an example, You can use the "version" property on the build.gradle file to manage SNAPSHOT/PATCH/RELEASE versions (e.g. 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT, 1.1.1-RELASE etc) and use git for source control. I hope this helps!

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. I was looking for ways to distribute the code without bundling it, so that debugging or modification is easy. But seems like created my a JAR file is the right way to do it.

Comment: The debugging/modification/bug fixes all should be done in the project and strictly maintained by release/snapshot/patch cycle. That way, the code remains stable and reliable. If you take a look at here: [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) you can see the release notes for a popular java library, you can see how they fix bugs, improve/add a feature and document it throughout the release cycle